# Haskell: Looking to add array field in data structure

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm new to Haskell.
I want to add an array field to my data structure, something like this:

```
data Level = Level
    { a :: Data.Array.Ix
    } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

But I don't know how to declare the field's type. It keeps giving me errors.

Comment: You probably want something like `Data.Array.Array Int SomeTypeHere`

Comment: `Data.Array.Ix` is a class, not a type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ix` is not a type, but a typeclass that the `Data.Array` functions use to provide indexing of different shapes of array. If you want an array itself, you need to use the `Array` type. It has two type parameters: the type of indices into the array, such as `Int` (for a 1D array) or `(Int, Int)` (for a 2D array), and the type of elements.

So for example, a 1D array of characters would have the type `Array Int Char`; you can create arrays using functions like `array`, `listArray`, or `accumArray`, e.g. in GHCi:

```
-- A 5-element array of characters
> example1 = listArray (0, 4) "abcde"

> example1 ! 2
'c'

-- A 3-element array of strings
> example2 = array (0, 2) [(0, "this"), (1, "that"), (2, "other")] :: Array Int String

> example2 ! 2
"other"

> example2 ! 3
*** Exception: Ix{Int}.index: Index (3) out of range ((0,2))
```

A 2D array of integers would have the type `Array (Int, Int) Int`:

```
-- A 3x3 matrix of numbers
> example3 = listArray ((0, 0), (2, 2)) [1..9]

> example3
array ((0,0),(2,2)) [((0,0),1),((0,1),2),((0,2),3),((1,0),4),((1,1),5),((1,2),6),((2,0),7),((2,1),8),((2,2),9)]

> elems example3
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

> bounds example3
((0,0),(2,2))

> example3 ! (1, 2)
6
```

So for instance if you wanted to represent a Tic-Tac-Toe board, you might use something along the lines of:

```
import Data.Array

data Board = Board
    { boardCells :: Array (Int, Int) Move
    } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

data Move = Empty | X | O
```

Which types you use depend on the actual problem you’re solving, of course.

Answer (score 1):

`Data.Array.Ix` is not a type, but rather a class of types which can be used as an index for an array (like `Int`).

You may want to use either `Array` from `Data.Array.IArray` (For immutable arrays), or `IOArray` / `STArray` from `Data.Array.IO` or `Data.Array.ST` (For mutable arrays). Something like this would work:

```
import Data.Array.IArray

type SomeType = String

data Level = Level
  { a :: Data.Array Int SomeType
  } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```